# Using Junit Standalone jar to run test Gives Class Not found

Tags: junit

I have a basic java program and a unit test written with `maven`:

I am trying to run the test with junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.9.2.jar -cp "." --class- 
path "*\target\test-classes" --class-path "*\target\classes" --select-class TestClass
```

But this Gives me `NoClassDefFoundError` for `MockitoAnnotations`.

Comment: You just added compiled classes from the project, but all other libraries (e.g. `Mockito`) are missing from the classpath.